# Is there a way to turn an entire data frame to Float when Reading in?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to understand if there is a way to convert an entire dataframe to a float when reading in with Pandas or do I need to create a function that does this after I've read in the data?

The data I'm using is and export from a facebook ads account. I'm only reading in columns that contain numbers and the only strings in the file are the headers.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

data = pd.read_csv("12776828-all-engage.csv", header=None, usecols=[4,6,7,8,11,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,25])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could specify, by giving `pd.read_csv` the argument `dtype=np.float64` (or `np.float16` or `np.float32` if the data will fit).

Usually, though, pandas can infer this itself. I noticed you mentioned that there are headers in the file. Leaving the `header` argument on the default of `infer` should also lead to the conversion of the contents to a numeric datatype.